# change content in all copied file by using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to change one line in my 10 text file by using python I have done this but this is not working

```
for i in range (2,11):
    shutil.copyfile("as-1.txt","as-%d.txt"%i)
    f=open("as-1.txt",'r')
    for line in f:
        if line.contains('init.in'):
            newline = line.replace('init.in', 'init.in%d'%i-1)
```

i did this by this way too

```
for i in range (2,11):
    shutil.copyfile("as-1.txt","as-%d.txt"%i)
    f=open("as-1.txt",'r')
    f.find("init.in")
    f.replace("init.in", "init.in%d"%i-1)
```

but these both are not working

Comment: What does `it is not working` mean? Do you save the file after your operations?

Comment: yes i did but it dont give proper output...

Comment: So what's the actual output and what's the expected output?

Comment: actual out put shoul be 10 copied file and content change as init.in-i in current file  but it makes copy properly but doesnot recoginize replace function

Comment: what is `line.contains`?

Comment: actual line is "  gfileStart = 'init.in'" and i want this as "  gfileStart = 'init.in-i' in all copied files

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
for i in range(2, 11):
    with open("as-1.txt", 'r') as fin:
        with open("as-%d.txt" % i, 'w') as fout:
            for line in fin:
                fout.write(line.replace("init.in", "init.in-%d" % (i-1)))
```

Comment: +1 for combining copying and replacing. Append `i-1` instead of `i`. Remove `t` mode.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thank you! I've corrected my answer.

Comment: you need parens around `i-1`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks again. This is what happens if you edit your answer without testing it first... :/

Answer (score 0):

To append in each newly copied file to `init.in` line its number (minus one):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput
import shutil

needle = 'init.in'
for i in range(2, 11):
    haystack = "as-%d.txt" % i
    shutil.copyfile("as-1.txt", haystack)
    for line in fileinput.input(haystack, inplace=True):
        print(line.replace(needle, needle + str(i - 1)), end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you copy the original file to n copies, then read
the original file line-by-line, modify in memory the interesting lines
and don't do ANYTHING ELSE

My approach,

```
# open for writing the copy files, my names may be different from yours but
# imho you are perfectly able to deal with this and other differences
handles = [open("file%d"%(n,),'w') for n in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)]

# now we open the original file
with f as open("file-1"):
    # we read it line-by-line
    for line in f:
        # if this isn't an interesting line just write it in each output file
        # you either def the "interesting" function or put the test inline
        if not interesting(line):
            for handle in handles:
                handle.write(line)
        else:
            # we loop ENUMERATING the output files
            for n, handle in enumerate(handles):
                # and instead of writing the line, we pass what a function
                # that you have to write is going to return
                # NOTA BENE, the modify function arguments comprise
                #            the index into the output files, so that
                #            it;s able to do what you want
                handle.write(modify(line,n))
# all the lines, modified or not, have been written to the outputs,
# the input file has been automatically closed, what remains to do?
for handle in handles:
    handle.close()
```

As you see, you need to fill the dotted areas but I hope that this is enough to get you started!  Please let me know in a comment if further clarification or help is needed.

Ciao